# Angular 2+ make a request every minute running a service

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am using angular 7 in a project and I was wondering how do I go by checking a result every (for example) minute but without having my application freeze.

So I have a service which requests data from an api:

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {

  baseUrl = 'some url here';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get_result() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/result');
  }

}
```

Component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.get_result().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

So the above is what I've got.

I need the process to check the result every minute without slowing down my application (because I will be having multiple processes doing this).

How can I do this?

Comment: if you need to check if the data has changed, you might want to use the websocket. The web api can notify the client that the data has changed and you don't need to periodically send request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your fetch code to some function and then use interval function something like

```
 fetchResults(){
    this.isProcessing=true;
     this.dataService.get_result().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.isProcessing=false;
    });
}
```

Then change ngoninit to

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.fetchResults()
    interval(60000).subscribe(val => {
    if (!this.isProcessing) {
    this.fetchResults();
    }
  })
  }
```

Here `isProcessing` property is to avoid fetching if already in progress.

Comment: this.isProcessing should be false in side 'subscribe'

Comment: Angular doesn't seem to know 'interval'

Comment: `import { interval } from 'rxjs'`